# BLDC motor control with STM32

Tags: c, stm32

I'm using the STM32 motor control API to operate a BLDC motor (GMB2804R) using the IHM16M1 driver. However, I'm encountering a delay issue when switching directions. Currently, there is a 500 ms delay that needs to be established for the motor to function properly. I'm unsure why specifically 500 ms is required instead of, for example, 499 ms. My goal here is to switch directions smoothly without any delays.

```
while (1)
  {
         //right
         MC_ProgramSpeedRampMotor1(2000, 0);
         MC_StartMotor1();
         HAL_Delay(3000); //run for 3s
         MC_ProgramSpeedRampMotor1(0, 0);
         MC_StopMotor1();
         HAL_Delay(500);

         //left
         MC_ProgramSpeedRampMotor1(-2000, 0);
         MC_StartMotor1();
         HAL_Delay(3000); //run for 3s
         MC_ProgramSpeedRampMotor1(0, 0);
         MC_StopMotor1();
         HAL_Delay(500);
  }
```

Comment: What happens if you delay for 499 ms? What happens if you don't delay at all?

Comment: With 499 ms set as delay, the motor stops for a few seconds and then starts running in the right direction again (doesn't switch direction). Same if I don't use delay at all.

Comment: From where did you get the 500ms? By testing or is it stated in some documentation?

Comment: I got the 500 ms by testing.

Comment: Though I have not worked with this specific motor, with my previous experience with BLDC motor, their was a delay/dead time involved when changing direction of the motor. All changes had it be gradual and not abrupt in my application. What is the load on your motor?

Comment: Are you suggesting 500ms works as expected, but 499ms or 501ms works incorrectly, or something like that? If that's the case, then this situation is a symptom of something else, no the root problem. Check if/how much voltage sags when the motor pulls current. This problem could have electrical engineering element to it.

Comment: @Ilya, any delay under 500 ms does not work but 501ms 502ms... works just fine.

Comment: @James this is weirdly specific, kinda too precise? As if nothing in there has any tolerances, and the cutoff time is 500ms down to nanosecond? Anyway, make sure the voltages stay okay throughout operation, it's the most common problem with motor projects. Also, as pointed out above, some delay is likely to be unavoidable.

Comment: What is the code you didn't show us? Can you please provide a compilable example? What is the schematic? Maybe https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ would be a better fit for this question?

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 it's an STM32 project. All I had to do was add those lines of code in the while loop. Not sure if I can provide a compilable example.

Comment: @Ilya that's true. As if the 500 ms was somewhere hardcoded in the MotorControl API.

Comment: @James STM32 is a processor, it doesn't provide any builtin functions. Please provide all the code you are using. If you use some non-standard library, you may ask the provider of that library why it doesn't work or look at their code. (Yet another reason not to use foreign libraries).

Comment: @1243123412341234123 I use the following Stm32 kit/tools to run the motor https://wiki.st.com/stm32mcu/wiki/STM32StepByStep:Getting_started_with_Motor_Control. These are provided by STMicroelectronics and are not considered as foreign libraries.

Comment: @James Edit the question so the the code is compilable. And to answer your question: Don't use foreign libraries. Of course they are forging libraries, there is no standard that defines them and there is no competitor that provides a alternative implementation for the same functions. Is it so hard to implement a that yourself? But hey, if you want to use them, do it, but don't be surprised when you get problems like this.